# "Failed to download" when creating new virtual maching in gnome boxes

Tags: 20.04, gnome, virtualization, gnome-boxes

so I just installed gnome-boxes on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When I click on the top left corner (the plus icon) and click "create new virtual machine", I select one of the "featured downloads" (i've tried all of them) Ubuntu, Red Hat, and openSUSE.

After clicking and trying to download it, it immediately tells me "Failed to download"

I've tried searching for other things to do, if I was missing any software, but couldn't find anything that I seemed to have been missing.

Comment: have you read through [this resource](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-boxes/stable/) from GNOME help?

Comment: I'll take a look there. I don't believe I looked on that resource page previously.
It does seem to work perfectly fine if I just download an ISO myself, but just doesn't work when I use their "featured downloads"

Comment: So... how to fix this? I really want to try this, but it fails and there is no reason why.